# Reverse Proxy Server and Webserver architecture

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, architecture

I'm very confused.

If I setup a Reverse Proxy Server, does this mean that I need a second computer? Or can both Server (e.g. nginx as reverse proxy server and apache as webserver) run on the same computer and different port!?

For example this pic!

[image]

it seems to me that there are 4 computers (one for each server) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A server is a process" said to me a teacher years ago :-)

Both servers can run on the same computer and different ports/IP.

For example you can set apache to

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

and then nginx point to it

```
server {
 listen   80;
 location / {
  proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
 }
}
```

Note that the above is pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

See [**here**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for a good intro on configuring reverse proxies in apache.

Since a web site is defined by an IP:port combination, nothing prevents you from running multiple instances or virtual hosts on one machine, with one instance pointing to or proxying another.

Comment: G Oh ok i understand. So i always thought the right way.:)

@adaptr  i already heard about mod_proxy. So i can have the same functionality as i would have with an second Server instance? If i want that all requests should be handled by the proxy server and the direct access point/address is hidden?

Comment: Yes; a common use of a proxy server is to hide the real origin server from the public internet.